# Cross Site Scripting Issue

Tags: javascript, html, security, scripting, xss

I want to prevent a XSS with our code, the problem is it might require both JS as well as html escaping and might be a little tricky.

The following sample code is similar to our code

```
 <script>
  var CURRENT_VALUE = '<img src=1 onerror=alert(1)>';
  document.getElementById("valueBox").innerHTML = CURRENT_VALUE;
 </script>
```

let us suppose CURRENT_VALUE is inserted dynamically. So what should I do in this case, I know a simple HTML encoding might not work as the attacker might pass the unicode escaped value and it might be dumped in the document when JS parser clears it.

So what is the correct way,

Should i first do JS escaping and just before document.getElementbyID do the html escaping ? How would that work ?

Assuming the CURRENT_VALUE is say hex encoded and contains /x027img... and so on

Comment: I dont see how this can be XSS related (?) Preventing XSS is more about sanitizing the content of input serverside. The above hides the <img> if you click "view source", but it does not prevent evil code from being inserted in an input box or textarea.

Comment: I would have thought anything client side was pretty futile when it comes to security. You have to presume that it can be manipulated and deal with the validation of proper/expected values server side.

Comment: The Server side JS escaping can be used, but if I have to use server side HTML escaping also, then i need to do it in the order first html escaping, following by JS escaping, as html is interpreted last but it might present problems when interpreted in a non html context, hence i might have to do server side JS escaping followed by client side javascript escaping, but I am not sure about this.

Comment: @davidkonrad If not escaped properly, the entire malicious script will be loaded into the document and hence is a xss

Comment: @davidkonrad This is about preventing DOM Based XSS: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS

Comment: @DarrenCrabb Not if you're securing your client-side domain from exploitation. By design most web apps the client-side contains sensitive data (e.g. auth cookies, output HTML containing personal details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I *think* I understand where you are heading - inserting the content as a TextNode does some formatting :

```
var CURRENT_VALUE = '<img src=1 onerror=alert(1)>';
var node = document.createTextNode(CURRENT_VALUE);
var valueBox = document.getElementById("valueBox");
valueBox.appendChild(node);

console.log(valueBox.innerHTML);
```

if you look at the console output the inserted HTML is now :

```
&lt;img src=1 onerror=alert(1)&gt;
```

Comment: yes, thanks :) , But I need to be clear on when this escaping should be done, if the CURRENT_VALUE is already escaped using JS hex encoding, all we have is /x026/x034 kind of right? so does the createtextnode of that input will be properly html escaped ? Thanks for the answer though

Comment: @Kalyan If it's JS hex escaped then `createTextNode` will interpret it as the unescaped value properly and all will be well.

Comment: Thanks makes sense, it might now work in non html context too with createTextNode